# Python QT5 combobox - save list,open method

Tags: python, combobox, qt5

I want to add a number in a separate window that will be displayed in a ComboBox after the new application launch. Maybe some base, I just don't know how to go about it. That's my code:

Maybe I could add some base?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel,QDialogButtonBox,QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, \
    QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QAction, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QDateEdit,QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
class Klient1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Klient1, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Klient")
        self.setFixedSize(300, 200)
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        self.combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.combobox.move(10,10)
        self.combobox.resize(100,25)
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('otworz',self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.btn.move(10,50)
        self.btn.resize(100,25)
    def add(self,nowe):
        dodaj = Dodaj_zlecenie()
        dodaj.exec_()
        wartosc = (dodaj.numer)
        self.combobox.addItem(wartosc)
        dodaj.show()
```

Next window:

```
class Dodaj_zlecenie(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Dodaj_zlecenie, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.QBtn = QPushButton()
        self.QBtn.setText("Dodaj")
        self.setWindowTitle("Dodaj do listy")
        self.setFixedWidth(300)
        self.setFixedHeight(100)
        self.QBtn.clicked.connect(self.nowe)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.listinput = QLineEdit()
        self.onlyInt = QIntValidator()
        self.listinput.setValidator(self.onlyInt)
        self.listinput.setPlaceholderText("Numer.")
        layout.addWidget(self.listinput)
        layout.addWidget(self.QBtn)
        self.setLayout(layout)
    def nowe(self):
        global numer
        self.numer = (self.listinput.text())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    MW = Klient1()
    MW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that is enough for me for the moment.

I added a value entry from the field to a text document.

```
text_file = open('file1.txt', 'a+')
with open('file1.txt', 'a+') as f:
    web_browsers = (wartosc)
    f.writelines("%s\n" % line for line in web_browsers)

    self.combobox.addItem(web_browsers)
```

Then in the 'combobox' field assign values ​​from the document.

```
        with open("file1.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        a = lines
        for i in a:
            self.combobox.addItem(i)
```

In the end, the code looks like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel,QDialogButtonBox,QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, \
    QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QAction, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QDateEdit,QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
class Klient1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Klient1, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Klient")
        self.setFixedSize(300, 200)
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):


        self.combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        with open("file1.txt", "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            a = lines
            for i in a:
                self.combobox.addItem(i)
        # self.combobox.addItem(a)
        self.combobox.move(10,10)
        self.combobox.resize(100,25)
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('otworz',self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.btn.move(10,50)
        self.btn.resize(100,25)
    def add(self,nowe):
        global wartosc
        dodaj = Dodaj_zlecenie()
        dodaj.exec_()
        wartosc = (dodaj.numer)
        text_file = open('file1.txt', 'a+')
        with open('file1.txt', 'a+') as f:
            web_browsers = (wartosc)
            f.writelines("%s\n" % line for line in web_browsers)

            self.combobox.addItem(web_browsers)
        dodaj.show()
class Dodaj_zlecenie(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Dodaj_zlecenie, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.QBtn = QPushButton()
        self.QBtn.setText("Dodaj")
        self.setWindowTitle("Dodaj do listy")
        self.setFixedWidth(300)
        self.setFixedHeight(100)
        self.QBtn.clicked.connect(self.nowe)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.listinput = QLineEdit()
        self.onlyInt = QIntValidator()
        self.listinput.setValidator(self.onlyInt)
        self.listinput.setPlaceholderText("Numer.")
        layout.addWidget(self.listinput)
        layout.addWidget(self.QBtn)
        self.setLayout(layout)
    def nowe(self):
        global numer
        self.numer = (self.listinput.text())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    MW = Klient1()
    MW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Maybe you have a better solution?